# How to test a binary clustering method?

Tags: clustering, k-means

I'm unsure in designing a test case for a clustering method of bitsets.

At the moment I define some centroids C like

```
C_ref = { 11110000
        , 00001111 }
```

with equal **Hamming**-distance (`c_i ^ c_j = 4`) to each other.

Now I create bitsets b like

```
B_ref = { 11010000
        , 11110010
        , 00001110
        , 00011111
        , ...      }
```

Every `b` has a distance (`b_i ^ c_n > 4`) to each centroid except to exactly one centroid `c_b`. The centroid cb and its corresponding b have a shorter distance (`b_i ^ c_b < 4`).

Maybe it's better explained in short with matrices

```
Distance|c_ref_0 c_ref_1
--------+---------------
c_ref_0 |      0       4
c_ref_1 |      4       0

Distance|c_ref_0 c_ref_1
--------+---------------
b_ref_0 |      1       7
b_ref_1 |      1       5
b_ref_2 |      7       1
b_ref_3 |      7       1
```

So my working steps are

```
create centroids C_ref as reference
create bitsets B_ref (with help of C_ref) as reference
find centroids C_res (with help of B_ref) as result
```

I check the distances of C_ref and C_res with

```
bitset-length 256 bit
8 centroids with distance 64 to each other
1000 descriptors with distance < 16 or distance > 64


Distance  | Centroids Ref 0 to 8
----------+-----------------------
Centroids | 0 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 
Ref       | 64 0 64 64 64 64 64 64 
0 to 8    | 64 64 0 64 64 64 64 64 
          | 64 64 64 0 64 64 64 64 
          | 64 64 64 64 0 64 64 64 
          | 64 64 64 64 64 0 64 64 
          | 64 64 64 64 64 64 0 64 
          | 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 0

Centroids | 32 68 34 36 39 32 32  4 
Res       | 32 68 34 36 39 32 32 68 
0 to 8    | 32 68 34 36 39 32 32 68 
          | 32 68 34 36 39 32 32 68 
          | 32 68 34 36 39 32 32 68 
          | 32 68 34 36 39 32 32 68 
          | 32  4 34 36 39 32 32 68 
          | 32 60 30 28 25 32 32 60
```

Looks not good. Nevertheless, what are your suggestions to test binary clustering?

## Update 1

Above I've tried (in a glumsy way) to ask how to test a clustering method of bit-vectors. Binary vectors are clustered with Hamming distance as distance-function into 8 or 10 clusters. The resulting centroids should be verified.

My approach is to create artificial centroids (like `C_ref` above) and produce artificial binary vectors (like `B_ref` above). Both sets are not random.

The clustering takes `B_ref` as input and produces `C_res` as output.

The last step is the distance matrix `C_ref X C_res`. A perfect result would be (in my eyes) `C_ref X C_ref == C_ref X C_res`.

Comment: There is some unclear points in your question and terminology. What is "binary clustering"? - binary data or clustering to two clusters? What is the use of centroids for binary (categorical) data? Expressions like `b_i ^ c_n > 4` are unclear, notation not explained.

Comment: I use binary vectors with 256 bit each. In total some billions of vectors. I try to cluster these binary vectors into 8 or 10 cluster. As so, I try to find 8 to 10 centroids.
I have adapted [link](http://imagelab.ing.unimore.it/imagelab/pubblicazioni/2013ElectronicImaging.pdf). `b_i ^ c_n > 4` means Hamming-distance greater 4.

Answer (score 2):

If you *predefine* the centroids, this isnot clustering, but **nearest neighbor classification.**

You can use any classification evaluation such as precision and recall.

Comment: I predefine centroids just for testing purposes. So to check if my implementation is approximating against the artificial centroids.